# Force close in Action Bar cativity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Why does this program force close when started?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    NPageAdapter nPageAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nPageAdapter = new NPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(nPageAdapter);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }
        };

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab "+i).setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
    }

    class NPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {

        public NPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new NObjectFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(NObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Object "+position;
        }
    }

    public static class NObjectFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                   R.layout.fragment_object, container, false);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(Integer.toString(bundle.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Update - The Log Cat ERRORS :

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.example.pageswiperexample, PID: 13954
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.example.pageswiperexample/ir.example.pageswiperexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hi. Why does this program force close when started?
Hi. Why does this program force close when started?
Hi. Why does this program force close when started?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error implies, you need to use a specific theme with this activity.

Open up `values/styles.xml` and change to something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

This is because your activity uses the support package, and you are (probably) trying to use a theme that's not in there (the support package). That could be something like the holo theme.